# Easiest, foolproof Ubuntu USB device?

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I'm a Windows and Android/Java programmer with no recent Linux experience. I want to help out some people doing Android development running Eclipse under Ubuntu. So I want to get up to speed on Ubuntu but I don't want to repartition or otherwise alter my Windows PC's hard drive.

I understand it's possible to make an external USB device like a flash drive (or external hard drive??) into a bootable Ubuntu environment. There are hundreds of "how to's" about this all over the web but in the "comments" section of many of them people say, "**no** don't do it that way, do it this *other* way..."

So I'm confused. Is there a simple, foolproof way to plug in a thumb drive (or USB harddrive???) into an otherwise-Windows PC and boot into Ubuntu Linux so I can do real work and install real applications and have a real file system, etc, etc, in that environment, without modifying my Windows PC?

Ken is correct -  I need a writable, persistent file system since I will be installing Eclipse and doing Android development.  Is there any place I can get a sense of the pros and cons of Virtual Box -vs- unetbootin?  In the latter, does the file system (for my apps and files) also live on the USB stick?   Is Virtual Box stable enough for a production environment?   Thanks in advance, again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need a fully installed Ubuntu and not just a bootable ISO on a USB stick (which is what most of the howtos refer to). The good news is, Ubuntu can be easily installed on a USB device, in exactly the same way you would install it to an hdd.

- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Another way would be to install Ubuntu in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows, and assuming your computer will boot from a flashdrive, unetbootin is very easy to use.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/

Runs on Windows, graphical interface.

[image]

An alternate would be to the desktop iso , burn it to a CD, and boot the CD

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

And the third option would be to run Ubuntu in a VM (Virtualbox).

https://www.virtualbox.org/

In Linux there are often multiple ways to accomplish your goal, one is not necessarily better. Choose the one that seems best for you and ask if you have a problem.

Comment: The problem with burning an ISO is that he needs more than a live CD, he needs an installation where he can install software and come back to it still installed.